# Flash interaction after flv video playback

Tags: flash, flv, interactive

I have a video embedded in Flash as an FLV. I'm able to get the video to play through the way I want, but when the video plays through and ends, I want to have two options/"buttons" display that allow the user to either replay the video a la youtube, or link to another web page.

I know it must a very basic question but I can't seem to find any answers. I've included a screen capture of the end of the video. Much thanks to anyone who can at least point me in the right direction if they don't want waste time trying to explain!

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to the [FLVPlayback](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html) complete event. This event is dispatched when the video finishes playing.